# Do Jasper support xml file as the datasource?

Tags: java, jasperserver

I want to know do JasperServer accepts xml file as the report data source and whether we can perform same operation on xml nodes that we perform on the various data-source in adhoc report creator like dragging dropping etc.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the sample Code I tested for xml file as data source and out is PDF report:

```
    JasperReport jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport("<Path of jrxml file>");
    JRXmlDataSource xmlDataSource = new JRXmlDataSource("<Path of xml file>", "XPath Query");
    JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, new HashMap(), xmlDataSource);
    JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfFile(jasperPrint, "<Path of file PDF output file>");
```

Answer (score 2):

yes, jasper does support XML based datasources, you can create your report just the way you would create it using any other datasource. Jasper has an abstraction from datasources which you provide to ensure  it behaves the same (or atleast similarly) with different datasources.

[look here](http://jasperforge.org/uploads/publish/jasperreportswebsite/trunk/sample.reference/xmldatasource/index.html) and [here](http://jasperforge.org/uploads/publish/ireportwebsite/IR%20Website/ir_xml_datasources.html) for some additional info

Comment: This is by using iReports. Can we do the same thing by JasperServer, Actually I am evaluating the community version of jasperServer. And I want to generate the reports by xml using same JasperServer jasperforge.org/projects/jasperserver –

Comment: iReport is designed specifically for JasperServer so the answer is "yes".

Comment: I mean to say just using JasperServer. JasperServer provides its own Adhoc Report creator. I want to use that to create report as xml as data source. Can you provide my steps or some link explaining this ?